# PHP echo $variable from function also writes ="" to html

Tags: php

The following PHP also writes `=""` to the html code instead of just writing the variable value as expected. 
How to get rid of the `=""` nonsense from the HTML code?

PHP:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $select = "";
    unset($id, $name);
    $id = $row['customerID'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    if ($_SESSION['customerID'] == $id){
        $select = 'selected';
        }
    echo '<option value="'. $id.'"'. "$select" .'>'.$name.'</option>';
}
```

HTML result with "selected" on the last line:

```
<form><select onchange="showUser(this.value)" name="id">
<option value="">Select Customer</option>
<option value="0">Customer2</option>
<option selected="" value="1">Customer1</option></select></form>
```

Expected result:

```
<form><select onchange="showUser(this.value)" name="id">
<option value="">Select Customer</option>
<option value="0">Customer2</option>
<option selected value="1">Customer1</option></select></form>
```

Comment: Are you seeing this from view-source or inspect element?

Comment: Did you use "view source" or chrome developers tools/firebug? Because developer tools can be different from source. Check in "view source"

Comment: Indeed. The actual source was fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The following PHP also writes `=""` to the html code instead of just writing the variable value as expected.

Whenever `if` condition fails you'll see this `=""` after `value` attribute. Your code should be like this:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    unset($id, $name);
    $id = $row['customerID'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    $option = "<option value='{$id}'";
    if ($_SESSION['customerID'] == $id){
        $option .= " selected";
    }
    $option .= ">{$name}</option>";
    echo $option;
}
```

Comment: May I know the reason of this downvote?